# SQL Server 2014 Loop untill the next row is not null

Tags: sql-server, loops

I am trying to select the second row in a column, I want to continue the loop if the next row is null.  Here is my script:

```
DECLARE @MAXID INT, @Counter INT, @clientId AS int 
SET @COUNTER = 2
SET @clientId = 11
SELECT @MAXID = COUNT(DISTINCT vw_masterView.LastVisitDate)  FROM vw_MasterView where clientId = @clientId;
WHILE (@COUNTER <= @MAXID)
BEGIN
SELECT  myData FROM 
(
  SELECT myData , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by  vw_masterView.LastDate desc) AS Rownumber
    FROM    vw_MasterView where clientId = @clientId 
) results
WHERE results.Rownumber =  @COUNTER  
 IF   Results.myData IS NOT NULL BREAK;
    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
END
```

I get the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "Results.myData" could not be bound.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a loop here in the first place? Loops should be avoided with the exception of a few administration tasks. If you can share some sample data and simple table structures we can help you find a set based approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable called `Results` in there. Set `myData` at variable and check `null` with the variable. Try this:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @myData VARCHAR(20)
  SELECT @myData = myData FROM 
  (
      SELECT 
       myData,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by  vw_masterView.LastDate desc) AS Rownumber
     FROM vw_MasterView where clientId = @clientId 
  ) results
  WHERE results.Rownumber =  @COUNTER  

  IF @myData  IS NOT NULL BREAK;
  SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the Results.myData is deeply flawed. You are not inside the query itself, so you can't reference a table and column. I believe this will accomplish what you are trying to do though.

```
DECLARE @clientId AS int = 11

SELECT 
   *
FROM (
   SELECT myData , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by  vw_masterView.LastDate desc) AS Rownumber
   FROM    vw_MasterView
   where clientId = @clientId 
   and myData is not null
) a
WHERE Rownumber=2
```